AssemblyScript library files in tsconfig.json
Using AssemblyScript to compile and run untrusted code server-side, I've added some additional library extending the standard library provided by AssemblyScript. These host function bindings are defined in a file, env.ts, which I've include during compilation using the --lib flag:
asc ./assembly/index.ts --lib ./lib/env.ts

Now I wish to configure a project, created using asinit:
npx asinit .

so that VSCode and other Typescript friendly IDEs recognizes the types in the env.ts file. What I currently have:
./assembly/index.ts
// The i32 AssemblyScript type is found and handled by VSCode
export function add(a: i32, b: i32): i32 {
  // Room is defined in env.ts. VSCode says: Cannot find name 'Room'. ts(2304)
  Room.describe("Test"); 
  return a + b;
}

In addition to the files created by asinit, I've added:
./lib/env.ts
File containing exported host functions and namespaces.

./lib/types/index.d.ts
Type declarations generated from env.ts using tsc --declaration

./lib/types/package.json
Contains: {"types": "index.d.ts"}

Is it possible to configure the ./assembly/tsconfig.json file so that VSCode will include the types defined in ./lib/env/types/index.d.ts as part of the built in library, without having to use import in index.ts?
./assembly/tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "assemblyscript/std/assembly.json",
  "include": [
    "./**/*.ts"
  ]
}


In order to add the types to the global scope, the file ./lib/types/index.d.ts must only contain ambient type declarations with no export or import statements.
The tsc --declaration flag may generate .d.ts files with export/import statements, so make sure all declarations are ambient without exports/imports.
Bad
export declare namespace Room {
    /* ... */
}

Good
declare namespace Room {
    /* ... */
}

Then, add all the paths containing type declaration files to the tsconfig.json file (either typeRoots to include folders, or types to add specific type files):
./assembly/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/assemblyscript/std/types",
      "../lib/types"
    ],
  },
  "include": [
    "./**/*.ts",
  ],
}

